# How do I delete a key in a dictionary array by condition in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

The Value column of the Test table stores JSON like:

```
{ 
  "type": "classic",
  "columnState": [
         {"colId": "a", "sort": "asc"},
         {"colId": "b", "sort": "asc"},
         {"colId": "c", "sort": "asc"}
      ]
}
```

How do I remove the "sort" key where "colId": "c" to get result like:

```
{ 
  "type": "classic",
  "columnState": [
         {"colId": "a", "sort": "asc"},
         {"colId": "b", "sort": "asc"},
         {"colId": "c"}
      ]
}
```

The number and order of values in columnState can change.

Data example:

```
DECLARE @Test table
    (
        id int,
        Value VARCHAR(1000)
    )
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES
        (1, '{"type": "classic", "columnState": [ {"colId": "a", "sort": "asc"}, {"colId": "b", "sort": "asc"}, {"colId": "c", "sort": "asc"}]'),
        (2, '{"type": "classic", "columnState": [ {"colId": "a", "sort": "asc"}, {"colId": "c", "sort": "asc"}, {"colId": "b", "sort": "asc"}]'),
        (3, '{"type": "classic", "columnState": [ {"colId": "a", "sort": "asc"}, {"colId": "b", "sort": "asc"}, {"colId": "c"}]')

SELECT * FROM @Test
```

Comment: For a single sort value: `select t.value, json_modify(t.value, concat('$.columnState[', k.[key] collate database_default,'].sort'), null)
from @test as t
  cross apply 
  (select o.[key] from openjson(t.value, '$.columnState') as o
  where json_value(o.value, '$.colId') = 'createdTask') as k`

Comment: @lptr Sorry, I can't figure out how to use this to UPDATE the right rows of the Test table.

Comment: `update t
  set value =  json_modify(t.value, concat('$.columnState[', k.[key] collate database_default,'].sort'), null)
  from @test as t
  cross apply……as k`

Comment: @lptr, an excellent solution, a possible problem here is when the `"columnState"` JSON array has more than one item with `colId` equal to `c`.